# Weird motherboard-USB-keyboard issue

Tags: usb, keyboard, motherboard, bios

In our company, we have many desktops with an [ASUS P5G41T-M LX motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5G41TM_LX/). We recently bought some cheap USB keyboards. **I have tested these keyboards on a desktop with an [AFOX
INTEL G41 (IG41-MA) motherboard](http://www.afox-corp.com/en/products_details.asp?proid=243&), and they worked perfectly fine**.

However, **when I try to use them on any desktop with an ASUS P5G41T-M LX motherboard** (in our company), **I always get the following symptoms**:

- Sometimes, I press keys and I get no response.
- When keys actually work, I frequently see the letter gets repeated multiple times, (e.g. when I try to type something like `admin`, I usually end up having something like `aaiinnn`).
- Pressing two keys simultaneously doesn't work most of the time.
- **The issues happen on all keys on the keyboard** (**they are not tied to a specific range of keys on the keyboard**, so there is no key that always repeats and another one that doesn't work. For example, pressing the same letter <kbd>A</kbd> might sometimes result in multiple `aa` and sometimes in nothing at all, and sometimes it might work properly).

Here is a list of what I've tried so far:

- Enabling and disabling `Legacy USB Support` in BIOS setup under USB configuration (with no effect whatsoever).
- Switching `USB 2.0 Controller Mode` between `HiSpeed` and `FullSpeed` in BIOS setup under USB configuration (with no effect whatsoever).
- Updating BIOS using `ASUS EZ flash2` to the latest ROM from the website (with no effect whatsoever).

I don't know what exactly can cause such behavior, but I can imagine that it can be related to clocks not being synchronized between the keyboard and the motherboard? And thus, some keys don't work (when they are not sent in the appropriate time), and some keys appear twice (when they are sent in a time that spans maybe two clock pulses of the motherboard). This is just an imagination and can be entirely wrong (please don't downvote based on that, and feel free to delete it out if it is wrong or misleading).

#### Note 1:

I know that most of the above symptoms can be related to a **damaged keyboard circuit**, or dirty keyboard buttons, But **the fact that the same new keyboard works fine on a motherboard of another vendor seems to disprove that**.

#### Note 2:

This **cannot be software/driver related**, since I have done some tests in the **BIOS setup screen**, and I can confirm the same behavior there. It also cannot be related to the USB port I am using, since I have tried the tests on different desktops with an ASUS P5G41T-M LX motherboard.

I currently don't care about these keyboards (of course, It would be nice if they worked), I am just curious. What can cause these kinds of *incompatibility* issues? Any ideas can help, thanks.

Comment: A guess: voltage on USB port a little to low for this keyboard. Connect the keyboard via USB hub that has its own power supply. Try it with both motherboards. If my guess is right the keyboard will work well with both of them or with none.

Comment: I remember I had such issue and it turn that some settings(sorry, cant recall exactly from memory) in BIOS related to some buffers was the case. When I disabled it, the weird keyboard start working. It also happened with ASUS computer

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski , thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't have such a USB hub. I will try installing another power supply unit and see if that matters. . .

Comment: @Alex , I searched for any BIOS setting with the keyword *buffer* in it. I couldn't find anything. Thanks for your suggestion anyway. . .

Comment: No, it wasn't related to keyboard but some USB setting that sounded like a good option, but I found later online that it is BIOS defect that ASUS not aware of it. Im sorry, can't remember how it was exactly named  :(