# Erratic Keyboard Behaviour

Tags: keyboard

I recently built a new PC with the following configuration.

1. Asus EX-A320M Motherboard
2. Ryzen 3 2200G processor
3. 8gb DDR4 RAM
4. UBUNTU 18.04

It was all working fine until suddenly my keyboard went nuts. Sometimes the keys dont response, sometimes multiple responses coming from single place. No specific key range having problem, all keys are behaving this way.
The exact description of the problem i found in an old post in this forum.

[Weird motherboard-USB-keyboard issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1167360/weird-motherboard-usb-keyboard-issue)
Posted 2 years ago, but no solution.

Things i have tried:

1. New keyboard, issue persists
2. Same keyboard works fine in another PC.
3. Upgraded ubuntu to 19.04, issue persists.
4. Reinstalled xserver-xorg-input-all, issue persists.
5. Issue remains even in BIOS.

I hope the problem description is clear. I can provide further info if required.

Please help with suggesting possible debug ways. I can replace the motherboard but i want too see the root of this problem.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**:

Not that anyone cares but I wanted this to be documented somewhere in public. I solved the issue. And the solution is **"GIVE IT SOME LOVE"**.

Yes, that's it, with the following characteristics.

- The keyboard only behaves normally when the person typing places a body part against the CPU cabinet. Otherwise, the keyboard misses/repeats key presses.
- Only the person typing, needs to make the contact. Someone else touching it doesn't work.
- Thus I have to put my legs on top of my cabinet and have developed a pretty weird coding pose.
- The entire system has been working for months like this without any other issues.
- This happens for any keyboard.

So probably this is some weird circuit situation between the motherboard and the CPU cabinet... and the keyboard ... and the user.

And honestly, at this point it has gone too meta to debug and I have learned to live with it.

Comment: someone could pranking you, be disconnect all other USB devices and retry

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me, but theres only 2 usb connected, keyboard and mouse. Removing the mouse doesn't fix it.

Comment: then it's almost certainly the motherboard.